# Is it tzedaka for someone to give a gift dependent only on his recognition?

Tags: rambam, tzedakah-charity, kavod

What does Rambam say about a person whose charitable donation depends on his getting recognition for it. Example: a person will donate the cost of building only if his name is on the building?

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam in Hilchot [Matnot Aniyim 10](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/986711/jewish/Matnot-Aniyim-Chapter-10.htm):7 codifies the hierarchy of giving in his view. Anonymous giving comes second

> The second level is to give to the poor without knowing to whom one
>   gives, and without the recipient knowing from who he received.
>
> The highest level is someone who supports a fellow Jew by endowing him
>   with a gift or loan, or entering into a partnership with him, or
>   finding employment for him.

R Asher Meir [learns from this](http://www.aish.com/ci/be/48893902.html) that

> The highest level of giving is someone who establishes a personal
>   relationship with the needy person, helping him with a loan or a
>   partnership in a way that doesn't make him feel subordinate.

R Meir explains the value of anonymity as avoiding to shame the recipient (which wouldn't be relevant to your building example)

> Part of the value of anonymity valued in this scheme is indeed due to
>   modesty, as Maimonides writes that an anonymous gift is "a commandment
>   fulfilled for its own sake", rather than done in order to obtain
>   honor. But an equally important consideration is to avoid shaming the
>   recipient.

and continues with thoughts relevant to your question

> Is it wrong to give charity in order to obtain honor? There are
>   contradictory sources on this issue. Many sources indicate that there
>   is no problem with this. Indeed, one of the most widespread methods of
>   collecting charity is precisely to sell honors, such as the Torah
>   readings in synagogue, and even so this is considered to be a
>   perfectly legitimate form of giving. [...] But it is permissible to
>   give the money if it will provide honor or status.
>
> Yet the Talmud tells us that giving charity in order to boast about it
>   is actually a sin! (Baba Batra 10b)
>
> We can resolve this paradox by examining the motivation. A person who
>   is motivated by the desire to help others deserves to be honored for
>   his efforts; it follows that he is perfectly permitted to enjoy the
>   honor, in a modest way. Even a person who seeks only honor but decides
>   to obtain it by helping others is still showing concern, though at a
>   lower level; it is certainly better than trying to gain recognition by
>   pride or excess.
>
> But if the original motivation is only to obtain recognition, and
>   there is no concern whatsoever for the needy individual, the gift is
>   not "charitable" at all. The donor is exploiting the recipient's state
>   more than he is trying to alleviate it.

Elsewhere R Asher Meir [writes](http://www.aish.com/ci/be/48893717.html) that

> The prominent medieval authority Rabbi Shlomo Adret writes that
>   honoring donors is not just a gesture to their vanity; it is a mitzvah
>   in and of itself to give honor to those who perform good deeds -
>   including giving charity.